# How did the Canaanites giants survive?

Tags: 1-samuel

Modern day giants (e.g. Robert Wadlow) often have serious health problems. Yet according to 1 Samuel 17:4 Goliath was six cubits and a span high (ca. 320cm). Any hypotheses as to how the giants survived without health problems? I know some will say Angelic DNA, but how spiritual beings can have DNA I don't know

Comment: I would not suggest anything other than simply he was a rare exceptional individual.  We do not know how old he was and perhaps would not have live long anyway???

Comment: How can we be certain that they did not have serious health problems? We know that they were abnormal humans, since they had too many fingers, and had a giant stature. However, we know this because it is the first thing noticeable. They could have had internal abnormalities too.

Comment: But Goliath was a philistine champion, he must have been physically capable.

Comment: Survived what then?

Comment: @ethos the health problems of gigantism

Comment: @ReggieO'Donoghue - Andre The Giant was "physically capable". Yet he died young from complications of gigantism. Who says being "physicaly capable" has anything to do with lifespan?

Comment: I’m not sure what’s being asked here. How did the Canaanite giants survive what, the flood? All the giants eventual died out, there’s no way to tell if they died, or lived with health problems due to their height.

Comment: The Septuagint of 1 Samuel 17:4 has *feet* instead of *cubits*, yielding a more plausible value of two meters. At any rate, there is an obvious biological difference between an excess of the growth hormone having a nefarious side effect on an otherwise normal human being, and someone whose very DNA is designed to grow naturally to towering heights.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if that is a good answer but couple of years ago i read interesting essay that connect the existence of "giants" to neurological disease on the pituitary gland that affect on growth hormone.

According to this when one suffer from that disease he become a giant' and he suffers from side effects that well describe on the story:

He moves slowly - as opposite to David that described running.

He suffer from lack on the field of vision - that's why he couldn't see the stone that David throw.

And he die younger - (as @DrPeterMcGowan point on his comment) we don't know how old he was, but assuming that he would win he would still (probably) wouldn't live long life.

Comment: There were other giants in Gath though, this isn't simply an isolated incident.

Comment: Indeed (i guess you refer to Joshua), but correct me if i wrong we won't get their ages.

Comment: Is this gigantism genetic?

Comment: I will try harder to find that essay.

Answer (score -1):

> "**There were giants in the earth in those days; and also after that,
>   when the sons of God came in unto the daughters of men, and they bare
>   children to them, the same became mighty men which were of old, men of
>   renown.**"

(Gen. 6:4 KJV)

The passage referred to in Gen. 6 must be understood in context: Angelic(or demonic) hosts cannot cohabit with men. This point is made clear when Jesus said stated in Matt. 22:29-30, when He said,

> **"Ye do err, not knowing the scriptures, nor the power of God. 30 For in
>   the resurrection they neither marry, nor are given in marriage, but
>   are as the angels of God in heaven."**

The angelic hosts, or fallen angelic hosts, lack the ability to procreate with man. But we see from Gen. 6 that they were able to "affect" them as spiritual beings in such a way as to alter their DNA, "creating", or perhaps "morphing" a giant. Since from the Scriptures we see Satan inflicting disease, sickness, and causing superhuman strength to exhibit itself in those who Jesus healed or delivered(See Mark 5, Luke 13:16). Apparently, this "DNA alteration" took place over a period of time, since in Gen 6:3 it says,

> **And the LORD said, My spirit shall not always strive with man, for
>   that he also is flesh: yet his days shall be an hundred and twenty
>   years.**

The descendants of Adam lived a thousand years, it allowed a race of people who's genetic structure was altered to become "giants". From the Book of Enoch, we read these giants tormented mankind and dominated them, possessing(and being "possessed") with superhuman qualities that weren't part of God's Original Creation.

Only 8 people(Noah, his wife, his 3 sons and their wives-Gen. 7:7) made it on the Ark, this generation of DNA altered individuals died off; although it appears that some survived in the Canaanite Nations that the Israelite's were intended to destroy,(Num. 13:33)

> **And there we saw the giants, the sons of Anak, which come of the
>   giants: and we were in our own sight as grasshoppers, and so we were
>   in their sight**.

Since none of Noah's children were giants, we can only surmise that the remnant DNA exhibited itself in the Canaanites-especially in the area called, "Valley of the Giants", or the Valley of Hinnom(Joshua 15:8).

In response to the question: "Giants" were not originally designed by God, they were "morphed" because of Satanic interference, therefore because of Satan's interference with God's Original Plan, defective DNA has interfered with His Creation throughout man's history. The physical prowess of these giants, from the story of Goliath was "of renown", the term used in Gen. 6:4, yet their strength was attributed to evil sources, not God. Though they were destroyed as a race by the Flood, they continued on in DNA, concentrated in the Valley of the Giants which Moses wiped out(Jos. 13:2). Any remnant today is a weak copy of what previously existed.

Comment: Is this a reference to the second view offered by Dr Heiser here: https://blog.logos.com/2017/11/who-or-what-were-the-nephilim/

Comment: @ReggieO'Donoghue No. I had not heard of him until you mentioned him. Angels(or demons) cannot copulate, they can "entice" and seduce men in imagination, but it requires a "man" to participate. What they CAN do is alter the chromosomal structure, but this took many generations(and a much longer life) to do. By God removing Satan's 1st attempt at creating a "superman", one that would terrorize and dominate man into submission to him, he was forced to try another way. That way is called "The Antichrist".

Comment: It still sounds like the second option presented. Where the Angels are responsible, though not through actual sex.

Comment: @ReggieO'Donoghue The "2nd Option", as I read it, takes a "euphemistic approach"(ie: Figurative) in describing the sexual contact. I disagree, they were actively seeking to have intercourse, and were involved in the stimulation, emotions, rise to climax that occurs naturally in humans. But since they don't have physical bodies to complete the physical act, they influenced the outcome through human vehicles. This is not a mere "metaphor", this is active participation to achieve a desired outcome. These "unions" became their 'property', by which continued to influence over time.

Comment: @ReggieO'Donoghue (cont.) But mere physically influencing these unions did not produce giants overnight, it required a continual coercion of the human subject until after repeated generations by humans living much longer than we currently do. Man was not "re-created"; his DNA was subverted to produce this offspring. That makes vs 3 of Genesis 6 significant: God saw and was grieved; His Spirit was also striving with man, therefore He limited man to 120 years-effectively neutralizing Satan's influence, as it took a significantly longer time to produce the giants.